# What could cause a Visual C++ 6.0 application to hang in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: visual-c++, stl, windows-server-2008, dcom

We have a product which is an emergency alerting system. It is based on VC++ 6.0, in which we have three major components

1. **Server**:  Server is basically a **DCOM** and Windows Service. DCOM is used to connect with **Console** (2nd component) to allow them to send alerts while service interacts with **Clients** (3rd component). 
   Using the application called **Console**, administrators connect to Server in order to configure the system and to send or schedule messages. Server then takes care of the task of dispensing alerts to all available Clients in near real-time.
2. **Console**: Console connects with server using DCOM proxy which uses RPC to communicate with server. It functions as control panel for the administrator to configure the various Server options, creating user accounts. On the other hand, it is used to initiate alert messages.
3. **Client**: Clients are standard Windows based applications. They connect with server using low level **TCP/IP** API’s. They poll server after short intervals to get the latest alert available.

The product is running successfully on the machines having (Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows Server 2003, or Windows XP) OS. But in Windows Server 2008, we are facing problem that Server gets hang after sometime (after 1 or 2 days) and hence the Console, so we need to restart the server to work properly. But Clients on the other hand remain connected with the server.

Does anyone with experience in this area have any suggestions that might help us to figure out what's causing this issue?

Comment: VC6 isn't supported anywhere anymore. It is not surprising if it doesn't work on the later versions of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Why not upgrade the VC6 project to VC2005 or higher, provided you have the source code?

- Check if compatibility runs can do anything positive.
- Check the  Windows Events for any possible issues.
- Use some File/Process monitor tool to find out any possible flaws in system.